# Android Lollipop compatibility test suite (CTS) for Leanback API

Tags: android, cts, leanback

I've been searching high and low for the CTS tests for the Leanback API. I haven't been able to find much but I might have found a lead here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/fcd4f02 This talks about a meta-data tag called "test_excluded_features" in the Android Manifest file of the CtsVerifier, and it kind of seems like this is excluding cts testing for leanback but I'm really unsure.

Does anyone know more about this or where I can find the Leanback CTS suite?

Google's documentation hasn't been very helpful here.

Thank you!

Comment: `leanback-v17` is part of the Android Support package. I am not aware that there would be compatibility tests for it, considering that it is not part of any device. I see [a few tests related to `LEANBACK` categories](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/tv/src/android/tv?autodive=0). Is there another "Leanback API" that you are referring to?

Comment: Hmmm... yeah maybe what I'm looking for doesn't exist. Thanks anyways